# phonegap audio don't stop

Tags: cordova, audio-streaming

I'm using Phonegap to create a player for a web-radio.

Playing the stream works great, but I can't stop the stream.
When I tap the stop button I have this message in log :

> AudioPlayer Error: stopPlaying() called during invalid state: 4

And on screen I have an "undefined" error. Seems my variable `my_media` is not defined.

Here is my code :

```
var src="http://stream.muzeeli.fr/ange";

var my_media = null;

function playAudio(src) {
    if (my_media == null) {                             
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
    } 
    my_media.play();
}


function stopAudio() {
    if (my_media) {
        my_media.stop();
    }
}

$(document).bind('pageinit',function(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {  
        $('#play').click(function(event){
            playAudio(src);
        });

        $('#stop').click(function(event){
            stopAudio();
        });
    }
});
```

I add a log file. Seems that status of the media is not well updated and has always the status MEDIA_NONE. So stop cannot be called.

```
E/MediaPlayer(23457): mOnSeekCompleteListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_SEEK_COMPLETE message.
V/MediaPlayer(23457): buffering 0
V/MediaPlayer(23457): callback application
V/MediaPlayer(23457): back from callback
V/MediaPlayer(23457): message received msg=200, ext1=703, ext2=193
W/MediaPlayer(23457): info/warning (703, 193)
V/MediaPlayer(23457): callback application
V/MediaPlayer(23457): message received msg=200, ext1=701, ext2=0
W/MediaPlayer(23457): info/warning (701, 0)
V/MediaPlayer(23457): callback application
V/MediaPlayer(23457): back from callback
E/MediaPlayer(23457): mOnBufferingUpdateListener is null. Failed to send    MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE message.
I/MediaPlayer(23457): Info (703,193)
E/MediaPlayer(23457): mOnInfoListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_INFO message.
I/MediaPlayer(23457): Info (701,0)
E/MediaPlayer(23457): mOnInfoListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_INFO message.
V/MediaPlayer(23457): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-110
E/MediaPlayer(23457): error (1, -110)
V/MediaPlayer(23457): callback application
V/MediaPlayer(23457): back from callback
E/MediaPlayer(23457): Error (1,-110)
E/MediaPlayer(23457): mOnErrorListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_ERROR message.
D/AudioPlayer(23457): on completion is calling stopped
D/CordovaLog(23457): playAudio():Audio Success
D/CordovaLog(23457): file:///android_asset/www/js/muzeeli.js: Line 40 : playAudio():Audio Success
I/Web Console(23457): playAudio():Audio Success at file:///android_asset/www/js/muzeeli.js:40
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Best,

Alain

Comment: What OS are you running on and what version of PhoneGap?

Comment: Hi Simon, I'm testing on Android with phonegap 2.1.0

Comment: Make sure both your .jar and .js are from 2.1.0. This reminds me of a bug I fixed for 2.1.0.

Comment: yes, both are in version 2.1.0

Comment: I didn't find a solution. I put all my code on github here : https://github.com/halbo5/muzeeli
If someone can help ...
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same problem

01-16 17:29:51.404: E/MediaPlayer(9903): mOnBufferingUpdateListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE message.

i try  @hyunkeln's code, i could solve it!!
thank u  @hyunkeln

the point is . put the code 'release' after 'stop'.

my_media.stop();
my_media.release();

Answer (score -1):

You need to call release() before stop() and check if my_media is still set and playing; maybe you wanna make things this way:

```
if (my_media != null && my_media.isPlaying()){
    my_media.stop();
    my_media.release();
}
```

Comment: No, you should not call release before stop. Also, the Media class does not provide an "isPlaying" method.